# Error converting miles to kilometers

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python and am attempting to create a simple formula that converts miles to kilometers and returns some text with the conversion.

Here's what I have:

```
def mile(x):
    z = x * 1.609344
    print "%.2f" % z

x = float(raw_input("How many miles are you traveling? "))  

z = mile(x)

print "That's about % kilometers." % z
```

Can someone explain why this doesn't work? I could definitely set up the mile function to print a sentence with the conversion, but I didn't want to do that.

Comment: Minor quibble: A function name like `mile(x)` is very unclear. For a tiny example like this it shouldn't matter but if other have to read your code, or you're coming back to your own project later, it doesn't say anything about what this does and that is potentially confusing. Something like `milesToKMs(x) would be much better.

Comment: Questions like this are a strong argument for not teaching beginners about `print` for a while.

Answer (score 10):

Your function needs to return the result.

```
def mile(x):
    z = x * 1.609344
    return z
```

Comment: so return will keep the output from the function in the script's memory?

Comment: `return` will return the value from the function. In the ordinary English sense of the word "return". A function, conceptually, is a box that you throw arguments into and get a return value out of. `z = mile(x)` means "throw `x` into the `mile` box, take whatever comes out, and call the result `z`".

Answer (score 1):

As way of an explanation:

You need to return the value of your computation/conversion from the function so that the result can be assigned to variable `z`. You can *then* print it out.

Before, you were printing the value *inside* your function, and not returning anything, which resulted in `z` getting assigned `None` which is why your print at the bottom didn't work.

In general it's best to do your work/computations inside the function and then return a value that you can decide how to use.

@wim shows the correct code for the function. If you now do

```
z = mile(x)
print "That's about %.2f kilometers." % z
```

you'll get the result you were expecting. (note the correct formatting as pointed out by @Aaron Dufour, you'll get 2 numbers past behind the decimal point when you print your result) Incidentally, your first `print` statement was correct, only the 2nd one was missing the complete formatting directive.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems.  The first is that your function does not return a value.  When the line `z = mile(x)` is run, the `mile(x)` part will be replaced by whatever is returned by `mile`.  The code you want is:

```
def mile(x):
    z = x * 1.609344
    return z
```

Note that it is irrelevant what variable you assign this to; it doesn't have to match the variable that is being returned.  For example, both `y = mile(x)` and `z = mile(x)` will assign to the given variable properly.

Second, your string formatting won't work.  This is that part that looks like `"That's about % kilometers." % z`.  The string formatting replaces `%<identifier>` with the given variable, where `<identifier>` tells what type the variable is (and possibly some info about how to display it).  You will need the identifier `f` or, like in the earlier print statement, `.2f`, giving `"That's about %.2f kilometers." % z`

Comment: +1 good catch about the string formatting, I updated my question to correct the print - hope you don't mind